# JSP 401 authentication

Tags: java, http, jsp, http-status-code-401

I'd like to implement a Java/JSP solution to return a client response to a web server that responded a 401 error to me when I try a wget for a resource.

How do I setup my JSP file to respond to the server with a username and password?
Any help with a simple example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as wget in java. do you mean the httpurlconnection class? if so, look at the authenticator class in the j2se javadoc.

Or consider apache httpclient which is much more pleasant.